# WPF MediaElement plays videos slowly

Tags: c#, wpf

It's completed project, and works on nearly 100 **stick PC**s. In one PC our **wpf application** **plays videos slowly**. But when I open video file with double click, it plays normal. And we have no that problem on another stick PC's. I searched and found answer like using another media player such as WPF MediaKit or VLC Player. If it's because of WPF MediaElement so why other stick PC's works with no problem. Is there anyone came across with this problem? It will be great if you share your experience. Thanks

We have DARK Stick PC and Windows 10 Home edition on PCs.

Comment: Which video player does play it smoothly? I'd guess it'd have to do with hardware acceleration or codec selection, where the player and the MediaElement differ. See also [Troubleshooting Video Playback in WPF](http://mrpfister.com/journal/troubleshooting-video-playing-in-wpf/).

Comment: Thank you for reply @CodeCaster, I will read article, and give feedback. If anyone else has experience on this problem please share.